# How to create sub network reference in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

The simple explanation for what I aim to do is the following

Given network O with structure of

```
---------           ----------            ----------            ----------            ----------
| Input | -> (x) -> | Blob A | -> (xa) -> | Blob B | -> (xb) -> | Blob C | -> (xc) -> | Output |
---------           ----------            ----------            ----------            ----------
```

I want to create a sub network to calculate a noise loss function for `Blob C`. The operation is given input `xb` with original output `xc`, and pass `xb + noise` through `Blob C` again to get `xc'`. Then the `mse_loss` is compute between `xc` and `xc'`

I have tried creating `nn.Sequential` from the original model. But I am not sure that it created a new deep copy or a reference.

If I have missed anything, please comment

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

So after some testing, I found out that if the layer references is kept (like in some variable), and then create a new model using nn.Sequential with that layer architecture, the new model will share the same layer reference. So when the original network is updated, the new model is also updated.

The code I used to test my hypothesis is the following

```
class TestNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestNN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 3, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        in_x = x
        h = self.relu1(self.conv1(in_x))
        h = self.relu2(self.conv2(h))
        h = self.relu3(self.conv3(h))
        return h

net = TestNN()

testInput = torch.from_numpy(np.random.rand(1, 3, 3, 3)).float()
target = torch.from_numpy(np.random.rand(1, 3, 3, 3)).float()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

def subnetwork(model, start_layer_idx, end_layer_idx):
    subnetwork = nn.Sequential()
    for idx, layer in enumerate(list(model)[start_layer_idx: end_layer_idx+1]):
        subnetwork.add_module("layer_{}".format(idx), layer)
    return subnetwork

start = subnetwork(net.children(), 0, 1)
middle = subnetwork(net.children(), 2, 3)
end = subnetwork(net.children(), 4, 5)

print(end(middle(start(testInput))))
print(net(testInput))

for idx in range(5):
    net.zero_grad()
    out = net(testInput)
    loss = criterion(out, target)

    print("[{}] {:4f}".format(idx, loss))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

print(end(middle(start(testInput))))
print(net(testInput))
```

The output before and after the training is the same. So I concluded that my hypothesis is correct.

To finish my objective, I created a 'transparent' loss like from [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/neural_style_tutorial.html) tutorial.

```
class NoiseLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, subnet, noise_count = 20, noise_range=0.3):
        super(NoiseLoss, self).__init__()
        self.net = subnet
        self.noise_count = noise_count
        self.noise_range = noise_range

    def add_noise(self, x):
        b, c, h, w = x.size()
        noise = torch.zeros(c, h, w)
        for i in range(self.noise_count):
            row, col = rng.randint(0, h-1), rng.randint(0, w-1)
            for j in range(c):
                noise[j,row,col] = (2*(rng.random()%self.noise_range)) - self.noise_range
        noise = noise.float()
        xp = x.clone()
        for b_idx in range(b):
            xp[b_idx,:,:,:] = xp[b_idx,:,:,:] + noise
        return xp

    def forward(self, x):
        self.loss = F.mse_loss(x, self.add_noise(x))
        print(self.loss)
        return x

noise_losses = []
testLoss = NoiseLoss(subnetwork(net.children(), 2, 3))
middle.add_module('noise_loss_test', testLoss)
noise_losses.append(testLoss)
```

and modify my loop to

```
    ...
    print("[{}] {:4f}".format(idx, loss))
    for nl in noise_losses:
        loss += nl.loss
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    ...
```

If I miss something, please leave a comment